# DataSet loses deep structure when elements have same name

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, xmlreader

I have an Xml file that contains multiple levels of  layers, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSet>
  <Test>
    <Test>
      <Step/>
    <Test>
    <Test>
      <Step/>
    </Test>
  </Test>
</TestSet>
```

As you can see there are two tests embedded within another test. When I read this into a DataSet I expect 4 tables, one table for each level of embedding.

```
DataSet.Table[0].Rows.Count == 1   // TestSet
DataSet.Table[1].Rows.Count == 1   // High level Test
DataSet.Table[2].Rows.Count == 2   // Low level Test
DataSet.Table[3].Rows.Count == 2   // Step
```

I am parsing the file using XmlReader like so:

```
XmlReader xmlFile;
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(file, new XmlReaderSettings());
DataSet data = new DataSet();
data.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

Instead when I use XmlReader I get:

```
DataSet.Table[0].Rows.Count == 3   // All of the Test items, High and Low level
DataSet.Table[1].Rows.Count == 2   // Step
```

Two problems, why does it skip over my TestSet level, and why does it combine my Test items into one table, despite being different levels.

Is there another reader I should use that would maintain the integrity of my data, or are there specific settings for XmlReader that would solve these issues, or am I better off reading in and parsing the file myself?

Comment: Have you looked at the columns in your tables and their names?

Comment: `DataSet` is an in-memory representation of a relational table structure. It cannot handle deeply nested XML. Please use LINQ to XML and process the XML as XML.

Comment: Yes, and all the data is present except the TestSet which has been ignored. The two tables are "Test" and "Step" with a relationship "Test_Step" also created. The XmlReader adds the columns Test_Id to both tables and Test_Id_0 to the Test table. Test_Id is the primary key and Test_Id_0 represents the parent Test for the two low level Tests... The embedded depth is there in it's own way, just not how I expect/want it to be displayed.

Comment: Can you change code that generated XML?  It only take one instruction to eliminate the two layers of Test tags.

Comment: The XML is correct as it is for this application. Most piratical uses will have 4 or 5 levels of embedded Test, so no the XML cannot change.